# (Python) How to make python program take a random line from a .txt file?

Tags: python

Hello i am new to python and i would like your help
So i just start learning and the first thing came on my mind is Why not edit a simlpe program !
Well i want to take a line (a username) and put it in an existing code

Here a part of the code

```
def getRandomUsername():
    username = 'Name_'
    for x in range(0,9):
            username = username + getRandomChar()
    return username
```

I want to pull from my .txt automatically a username and replace it with the hole thing
any ideas ?

As i told im very new to this type of thing also sorry for my bad engls

--

Thanks Guys

Comment: This may have been answered before! http://stackoverflow.com/q/14924721/823470 Good luck with Python.

Comment: The accepted answer on that question is not really high quality in my opinion.

Comment: But the answer with the highest votes seem fine. Which is what you copy/pasted into this Q&A, so it's definitely a duplicate.

Comment: In my defence, I just didn't expect the best answer to be at the bottom of the list.

Comment: @Donkey32, please ask a new question for the new problem rather than adding on to an existing one - the new error seems completely unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text file is not particularly large, you can read the whole thing into memory and select a random one:

```
import random

# You can do this once in your program
lines = open('filename').read().splitlines()

# Whenever you need a new random line, you do this
randomline = random.choice(lines)
```

Comment: In that case you could substitute open('filename').read().splitlines() with open('filename').readlines()

Comment: `splitlines` has the advantage that it consumes the newline character, which is probably what is wanted here.

Answer (score 0):

This is for integer random that is shown `testfile.txt`

```
import random
file = open("testfile.txt","w")
file.write(str(random.randint(3,115)))
file.close()
```