# How to select a random line from a .txt file in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, random

I want to create a program that randomly prints out a line from a .txt file. This is where I'm currently at, and the only other similar questions I could find were in other languages. For example, Python with the `random.choice()` operation, which I found in this question: [How to choose a random line from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924721/how-to-choose-a-random-line-from-a-text-file)

Thank you all for your time!

```
fun main() {
    val file = "text.txt"
    println(file.random("text.txt")) //This code doesn't work, I'm just illustrating what I was looking to do.
}
```

Edits I felt were necessary:
The libraries I'm Importing.

```
import java.io.FileReader
import kotlin.system.exitProcess
import java.io.FileWriter
import kotlin.random.Random
```

More things I've learned:

There is a function `RandomAccessFile` which is used for the exact purpose of what I want to do, however, I am not finding any good sources for how to use it within Kotlin.

Edits for Comments:
I can read from the file and when I do so all of the lines get printed in order.

1: I know how to generate random numbers, however, I don't know how to add that to the .txt file.

2: I attempted to use the following code to be able to add a number corresponding to the line it was on, however, this code gave me an error for running where the i variable was not understood as an existing number.

**ERRORED CODE BELOW AND IN PASTEBIN FOR TIDYNESS.**
https://pastebin.com/FxFWjv37

```
fun main() {
    var i = 1
    println("Please input a value, type DONE when done, READ to print.")
    val loop = 0
    while (loop < 1) {
        var response = readLine()
        if (response == "DONE") {
            exitProcess(0)
        }else if (response== "READ") {
            RandomRead()
        } else {
                WriteToFile(i + response)
            i+1
        }
    }
}
```

*Error:(23, 31) Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:*

*public final operator fun plus(other: Byte): Int defined in kotlin.Int*

*public final operator fun plus(other: Double): Double defined in kotlin.Int*

*public final operator fun plus(other: Float): Float defined in kotlin.Int*

*public final operator fun plus(other: Int): Int defined in kotlin.Int*

*public final operator fun plus(other: Long): Long defined in kotlin.Int*

*public final operator fun plus(other: Short): Int defined in kotlin.Int*

I also attempted:

```
fun main() {
    println("Please input a value, type DONE when done, READ to print.")
    val loop = 0
    while (loop < 1) {
        var response = readLine()
        if (response == "DONE") {
            exitProcess(0)
        }else if (response== "READ") {
            RandomRead()
        } else {
                WriteToFile(response)
        }
    }
}
fun WriteToFile(str: String?) {
    var i = 0
    try {
        var fo=FileWriter("test.txt")
        fo.write(i + " " + str + "\n")
        fo.close()
        i+1
    }catch (ex:Exception){
        println(ex.message)
    }
}
```

*Error:(37, 20) Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:*

*public final operator fun plus(other: Byte): Int defined in kotlin.Int*

*public final operator fun plus(other: Double): Double defined in kotlin.Int*

*public final operator fun plus(other: Float): Float defined in kotlin.Int*

*public final operator fun plus(other: Int): Int defined in kotlin.Int*

*public final operator fun plus(other: Long): Long defined in kotlin.Int*

*public final operator fun plus(other: Short): Int defined in kotlin.Int*

Comment: Can you read the text file line by line?  Do you know how to generate random integers?

Comment: Look into the `readLines` extension function for a `File` object, that gives you a `List<String>`. Then you only need to pick a random line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use [`readLines()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-lines.html) in combination with [`random()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-elements.html#random-element):

```kotlin
File("file.txt").readLines().random()
```

But, as the documentation of `readLines()` says:

> Do not use this function for huge files.